# Google Play shows Unoptimized APK for Cordova App

Tags: android, cordova, google-play

I was trying to publish my first Cordova app on Google Playstore.
When I upload my release apk, it shows below warning and I cannot rollout the release.

Unoptimized APK

Warning:

This APK results in unused code and resources being sent to users. Your app could be smaller if you used the Android App Bundle. By not optimizing your app for device configurations, your app is larger to download and install on users’ devices than it needs to be. Larger apps see lower install success rates and take up storage on users’ devices.

Comment: got any solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is just a warning, and you can carry on uploading Cordova APKs. The Cordova team know about this, and you can follow [their feature request to support Android App Bundle here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/729)

Answer (score 33):

Well, it's just a warning I think. You could ignore it and rollout the release. 
The problem is that **you haven't completed and provided enough information for important contents like store listing, content rate, pricing & distribution, and app release**. When all of them show "green check", you could rollout the app.

Comment: so, you say, if these information is filled in, https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/729 is no more an issue?

Comment: @Asqan Fill in all these information is just a way help you release your app immediately. It will skip App Bundle problem, but it don't solve completely the warning from Google.

Comment: I just tested this today and I totally second what @GiaÂnNgôTriệu has to say.

Answer (score 2):

According to your mention problem, you can solve in `cordova 9.0.0` by this way:
`Go to` your respective project directory, then go to `platforms/android` directory, then open `cmd`/`terminal` and write this `command` as `gradlew bundle`. After completing this process, It'll be generated `app.aab`. You can find the output into the `outputs/bundle` directory.

Answer (score 1):

The disadvantage is what i saw is, that in the Play Store there will be a message " your app might not be optimized for your device" that is annoying, and this may force you to use the bundle and Google's signing. Because people might consider not to use your app, while in fact there is nothing wrong with it. Even if an app is just 12MB, Google is going to say that it is too big.
But i don't know if it works corectly if you use the bundle method with apps not generated by Android Studio.

Comment: Is this documented some place on the android documentation?

Comment: once you are in the developers console you'll get links to the info about it and else you can find it on developer.android.com

Answer (score 0):

The youtube video explains it well and with the appropriate solution.

[Click Here for Youtube Video Explanation and solution](https://youtu.be/f72MbE4-Yyw)

Comment: Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) , and be sure with your [answer link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259)
 While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.
 [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

This is a new policy from Google, now, instead of submitting the apk, we need to generate a bundle, and the Play Store itself will generate the app.

The steps are:

1. Navigate to your platforms/android folder inside your project;
2. Execute ./gradlew bundle;
3. Sign the bundle as you would the apk;
4. Send it to the Play Store;

More details here: https://medium.com/swlh/generating-an-android-app-bundle-from-your-ionic-app-without-android-studio-5bc3acaf4528