# React Native - Unoptimized APK to submit my app to Google Play

Tags: android, react-native

getting waring in Google Play Store

[image: this warning are showing in my google play store]

Comment: you can ignore this. They are recommending their new feature called `Android App Bundle`.

Comment: you can read more on this here https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Play shows Unoptimized APK for Cordova App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56031952/google-play-shows-unoptimized-apk-for-cordova-app)

Comment: I m also facing the same issue. I have upgraded RN 0.55.4 => 0.59.9. Don't know what to do? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just build and upload aab (Android App Bundle) file instead of apk .

```
cd android
./gradlew bundleRelease
cd ..
```

aab file will be placed in"/android/app/build/outputs/bundle/release/"