# Not able to upload 1.13 mb apk to google play store it need aab file

Tags: android, apk, bundle

I have created an app using visual studio 2017 apache cordova. I published it and it created an apk of 1.13MB. I tested it on android and it's working. When I started to upload it to play store it gave me a warning.

Unoptimized APK
Warning:

This APK results in unused code and resources being sent to users. Your app could be smaller if you used the Android App Bundle. By not optimizing your app for device configurations, your app is larger to download and install on users' devices than it needs to be. Larger apps see lower install success rates and take up storage on users' devices.

Resolution:

Use the Android App Bundle to automatically optimize for device configurations, or manage it yourself with multiple APKs.

I tried to convert it to aab using android studio but it did not work.

How can I solve this?

Comment: That’s only a warning, not an error, so you were able to upload the file? Please explain what exactly you did to create AABs and what didn’t work? Errors? Couldn’t find where to do it? Something else? Please be specific so we can help you with the specific issue

Comment: No there is no option for to rollout. Start rollout to production button is disabled. the app or submit it just discard option

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Play shows Unoptimized APK for Cordova App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56031952/google-play-shows-unoptimized-apk-for-cordova-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you can't rollout is unrelated to this warning.

Warnings do not block the release. The fact that the button is disabled is a sign that something else is incomplete: check your store listing, the pricing distribution, etc. And make sure that all required checkboxes are checked.